# Why is prop showing not defined?

Tags: javascript

So I have this code which Im running on Freecodecamp. Can't understand why its showing prop is not defined.

prop is actually taking values from the function when its called. Unlike prop, name isn't coming as not defined.

```
var contacts = [
{
    "firstName": "Akira",
    "lastName": "Laine",
    "number": "0543236543",
    "likes": ["Pizza", "Coding", "Brownie Points"]
},
{
    "firstName": "Harry",
    "lastName": "Potter",
    "number": "0994372684",
    "likes": ["Hogwarts", "Magic", "Hagrid"]
},
{
    "firstName": "Sherlock",
    "lastName": "Holmes",
    "number": "0487345643",
    "likes": ["Intriguing Cases", "Violin"]
},
{
    "firstName": "Kristian",
    "lastName": "Vos",
    "number": "unknown",
    "likes": ["JavaScript", "Gaming", "Foxes"]
}
];


function lookUpProfile( name, prop){
// Only change code below this line

switch(name) {
  case "Akira":
  case "Harry":
  case "Sherlock":
  case "Kristian":
  for ( var j=0; j<contacts.length;j++) {
  if(contacts[j].firstName == name) {
    return contacts[j][prop];
  } else {
     console.log("No such contact");
  }
}break;
}
}

if (!contacts.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
  console.log("No such property");
// Only change code above this line
}

// Change these values to test your function
lookUpProfile("Kristian", "lastName");`
```

Comment: "contacts" is your array, it will not have a "lastName" property. But an item IN the array does have it

Answer (score 1):

This is why proper code indentation is important. Your if statement is outside of your function so `prop` does not exist in the scope which you're trying to use it in. Move your if statement into the function `lookUpProfile` and it won't be undefined.

```
var contacts = [
  {
    "firstName": "Akira",
    "lastName": "Laine",
    "number": "0543236543",
    "likes": ["Pizza", "Coding", "Brownie Points"]
  },
  {
    "firstName": "Harry",
    "lastName": "Potter",
    "number": "0994372684",
    "likes": ["Hogwarts", "Magic", "Hagrid"]
  },
  {
    "firstName": "Sherlock",
    "lastName": "Holmes",
    "number": "0487345643",
    "likes": ["Intriguing Cases", "Violin"]
  },
  {
    "firstName": "Kristian",
    "lastName": "Vos",
    "number": "unknown",
    "likes": ["JavaScript", "Gaming", "Foxes"]
  }
];


function lookUpProfile(name, prop) {
  // Only change code below this line
  if (!contacts.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
    console.log("No such property");
    // Only change code above this line
  }
  switch(name) {
    case "Akira":
    case "Harry":
    case "Sherlock":
    case "Kristian":
      for (var j = 0; j < contacts.length; j++) {
        if(contacts[j].firstName === name) {
          return contacts[j][prop];
        } else {
          console.log("No such contact");
        }
      } break;
  }
}

// Change these values to test your function
lookUpProfile("Kristian", "lastName");
```